# Create a new contract but keep getting this error this contract may be abstract not implement an abstract parents methods

Tags: solidity, remix

Here is my code.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    
    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // ETH -> USD conversión rate 
        
    }
    
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and share the steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.